# Accessing files in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-sacred

I am using sacred package in python, this allows to keep track of computational experiments i'm running. sacred allows to add observer (`mongodb`) which stores all sorts of information regarding the experiment (`configuration`, `source files` etc).
`sacred` allows to add artifacts to the db bt using `sacred.Experiment.add_artifact(PATH_TO_FILE).`

This command essentially adds the file to the DB.

I'm using MongoDB compass, I can access the experiment information and see that an artifact has been added. it contains two fields:
'`name`' and '`file_id`' which contains an `ObjectId`. (see image)

I am attempting to access the stored file itself. i have noticed that under my db there is an additional `sub-db` called `fs.files` in it i can filter to find my `ObjectId` but it does not seem to allow me to access to content of the file itself.

[image: object id under .files]

[image: file_id under artifact/object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB file storage is handled by "GridFS" which basically splits up files in chunks and stores them in a collection (fs.files).

Tutorial to access: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/gridfs.html

Comment: access denied to link

Answer (score 2):

Code example for [`GridFS`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/gridfs.html) (`import gridfs, pymongo`)

If you already have the `ObjectId`:

```
artifact = gridfs.GridFS(pymongo.MongoClient().sacred)).get(objectid)
```

To find the `ObjectId` for an artifact named `filename` with `result` as one entry of `db.runs.find`:

```
objectid = next(a['file_id'] for a in result['artifacts'] if a['name'] == filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small library called `incense` to access data from MongoDB stored via sacred. It is available on GitHub at https://github.com/JarnoRFB/incense and via pip. With it you can load experiments as Python objects. The artifacts will be available as objects that you can again save on disk or display in a Jupyter notebook

```py
from incense import ExperimentLoader

loader = ExperimentLoader(db_name="my_db")
exp = loader.find_by_id(1)
print(exp.artifacts)
exp.artifacts["my_artifact"].save()  # Save artifact on disk.
exp.artifacts["my_artifact"].render()  # Display artifact in notebook.
```

Comment: This looks great!